# Best Material(s) for Casting Large Volume Clear Rubber Object

Tags: material-selection, casting, rubber, material-sourcing

I am working on a project where I'd like to suspend several objects in a 12" x 12" x 12" clear rubber cube. This is meant to be an art object, so longterm durability is important.

In researching casting rubber options, it seems like a lot of the nicer more durable options are meant for smaller volumes, and are cost prohibitive at this scale. Meanwhile the more affordable options mention that they'll decay over time.

Here are a couple I've been looking at that seem representative of the options:

Urethane casting rubber, durable but expensive: https://www.smooth-on.com/products/clear-flex-30/

Latex, cheap but will decay: https://douglasandsturgess.com/products/latex-10-clear-5-gal

Is there another option I could look into, or some way of combining these materials?

I thought of maybe making a 10"x10"x10" latex cube and then surrounding the outside with urethane. Would that be viable and prevent decay over time? Or is there another material I can check out?

Comment: Does is have to be *rubber*? Meaning: will somebody actually touch the object and feel its rubbery consistency? How much force does it have to withstand? Like gentle touch or bouncing the whole thing? Or is it the kind of artwork nobody is supposed to touch?

Comment: @Elmy Rubbery consistency is important. The idea is to embed a haptic motor in the rubber and have it visibly vibrate the whole mass. The artwork is meant to be a gallery piece, so doesn't have to be children's museum durable, but should stand up to someone putting their hands on it or general wear and tear during transport